# Insertion Sort / Heap Sort time complexity

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, heapsort, insertion-sort

Assume you have to sort an array with `n = 1,000,000` elements. How long would insert sort and heapsort roughly need assuming each basic step takes one milli-second?

---

I know that insert sort takes `n^2` steps in the worst case, and heapsort takes `n log n` steps in the worst case.

So `1,000,000 ^ 2` for insertion sort = `1*10^12` milli-seconds

and `1,000,000 * log(1,000,000)` for heap-sort? `6,000,000` milli-seconds

is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Well...

The problem is that "order" notation is only talking about limits and comparisons, not absolute times.  It also leaves off constants and lower order terms.

For example (this is totally fictitious), the actual running time for the specific insertion sort implementation you might be looking at could be:

```
num steps = 45,334 * n^2 + 6,500,000 * n + 2,000,000
```

That is an `O(n^2)` algorithm, but it'll take a lot more time than what you've computed.